# Isometry group question

Tags: group-theory

The isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\def\Isom{\operatorname{Isom}}$
\begin{eqnarray*} \Isom_n(\mathbb{R})=\{f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n: f ~  \text{is an isometry}\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

How to prove that \begin{eqnarray*}\Isom_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \left\{\begin{bmatrix} A & \mathbf{t}  \\ \mathbf{0} &  1\end{bmatrix}: A\in O(n), \mathbf{t}\in \mathbb{R}^n \right\}?
\end{eqnarray*}

Here $O(n)$ is the $n\times n$ orthogonal group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we identify $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the hyperplane of points
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    {\bf x} \\
    1
\end{pmatrix}
\in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}, \qquad {\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
then the given group of block matrices acts on this space by left multiplication. One can then show directly that this action preserves the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How you show the converse (i.e., that *any* isometry is of this form) depends on what you already know, but if you know that $O(n)$ is the group of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that preserves the standard inner product, then the claim follows quickly after composing with a translation to reduce to the case that an isometry fixes, say, the origin.

Comment: What is the reference of this? Did you use a book?